# Virtual Server 2008 too fast for old web application

Tags: windows-server-2008

We have installed an old web application called HAHTsite on a Windows 2008 virtual server.  The issue we seem to be having is that the server is too fast for the application.  When submitting a form that creates a url, the application throws an internal error.  If you highlight the url in the address bar and hit Enter after the error is displayed, it goes on to the next page as it is supposed to do.  The same application runs fine when installed on a virtual 2003 server.  Is there any way to slow processing down via IIS7 or other method?

Comment: What please is Virtual Server 2008?

Comment: how many vcpu's and of what type, just pick a slow vcpu.

Comment: I'm hoping he's using hyper-v and has a web server thats a guest!